# What does the vector to raster option in QGIS do, exactly?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have a large point vector layer (a few million objects) with measured elevation values and have converted it to raster, using the **raster>conversion>(vector to raster)** option in QGIS. It seems to work fine, but I haven't been able to find info on how it exactly the value for a pixel is computed.

Does QGIS take the average of all points in the cell, the median, the first object it finds in the attribute table, etc.?

Is there perhaps a plugin with options for this?

Comment: The joy of open-source is that you don't have to guess, just dig down deep enough in the source tree to locate the code.

Comment: I suspect you'll find the scanline fill algorithm alive and well.

Comment: @Vince the gvBurnScanLine function is definitely still there but the function used is GDALdllImageLine or GDALdllImageLineAllTouched that is actually used in gv_rasterize_one_shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In gdalrasterize.cpp, function `CPLErr GDALRasterizeGeometries`, line 715 to 742 in my local snapshot (line 885 to 914 of [the online source](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/alg/gdalrasterize.cpp) at the time of writing):

```
    eErr =
        poDS->RasterIO(GF_Read,
                       0, iY, poDS->GetRasterXSize(), nThisYChunkSize,
                       pabyChunkBuf,
                       poDS->GetRasterXSize(), nThisYChunkSize,
                       eType, nBandCount, panBandList,
                       0, 0, 0, NULL);
    if( eErr != CE_None )
        break;

    for( int iShape = 0; iShape < nGeomCount; iShape++ )
    {
        gv_rasterize_one_shape( pabyChunkBuf, iY,
                                poDS->GetRasterXSize(), nThisYChunkSize,
                                nBandCount, eType, bAllTouched,
                                reinterpret_cast<OGRGeometry *>(
                                                    pahGeometries[iShape]),
                                padfGeomBurnValue + iShape*nBandCount,
                                eBurnValueSource, eMergeAlg,
                                pfnTransformer, pTransformArg );
    }

    eErr =
        poDS->RasterIO( GF_Write, 0, iY,
                        poDS->GetRasterXSize(), nThisYChunkSize,
                        pabyChunkBuf,
                        poDS->GetRasterXSize(), nThisYChunkSize,
                        eType, nBandCount, panBandList, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
```

For those that don't speak C the key is `for( int iShape = 0; iShape < nGeomCount; iShape++ )` which means that values are overwritten without checking if the cell already has a value... so it's the *last geometry in the cell that sets the final value*.